# How to combine LSTM and CNN models in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I have users with profile pictures and time-series data (events generated by that users).
To make a binary classification, I wrote two models: LSTM and CNN which work good independently. But what I really want to achieve is to concatenate these models.

Here is my LSTM model:

```
input1_length = X_train.shape[1]
input1_dim = X_train.shape[2]

input2_length = X_inter_train.shape[1]
input2_dim = X_inter_train.shape[2]

output_dim = 1

input1 = Input(shape=(input1_length, input1_dim))
input2 = Input(shape=(input2_length, input2_dim))

lstm1 = LSTM(20)(input1)
lstm2 = LSTM(10)(input2)

lstm1 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(lstm1)
lstm1 = Dropout(0.5)(lstm1)
lstm1 = Dense(12, activation='relu')(lstm1)

lstm2 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(lstm2)
#lstm2 = Dropout(0.5)(lstm2)
lstm2 = Dense(12, activation='relu')(lstm2)

merge = concatenate([lstm1, lstm2])

# interpretation model
lstm = Dense(128, activation='relu')(merge)

output = Dense(output_dim, activation='sigmoid')(lstm)

model = Model([input1, input2], output)
optimizer = RMSprop(lr=1e-3, decay=0.0)

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

CNN model:

```
def gen_img_model(input_dim=(75,75,3)):
    input = Input(shape=input_dim)

    conv = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu')(input)
    conv = MaxPooling2D((3,3))(conv)
    conv = Dropout(0.2)(conv)

    conv = BatchNormalization()(conv)


    dense = Dense(128, activation='relu', name='img_features')(conv)
    dense = Dropout(0.2)(dense)

    output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dense)

    optimizer = RMSprop(lr=1e-3, decay=0.0)

    model = Model(input, output)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

Here is how CNN is trained:

```
checkpoint_name = './keras_img_checkpoint/img_model'
callbacks = [ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_name, save_best_only=True)]

img_model = gen_img_model((75,75,3))

# batch size for img model
batch_size = 200

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)


# train gen for img model
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        './dataset/train/',
        target_size=(75, 75),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='binary')

val_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        './dataset/val/', 
        target_size=(75, 75),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='binary')


STEP_SIZE_TRAIN = train_generator.n // train_generator.batch_size
STEP_SIZE_VAL = val_generator.n // val_generator.batch_size

img_model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=STEP_SIZE_TRAIN,
        validation_data=val_generator,
        validation_steps=800 // batch_size,
        epochs=1,
        verbose=1,
        callbacks=callbacks
)
```

What would be the best way to concatenate LSTM and CNN models together?

Comment: How did you reshape the input shapes from CNN --> LSTM by using the generator?

Answer (score 1):

```
This is how you can merge two Deep learning models.

    model1 = Sequential()
    #input 
    model1.add(Dense(32, input_shape=(NUM_FEAT1,1)))
    model1.add(Activation("elu"))
    model1.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model1.add(Dense(16))
    model1.add(Activation("elu"))
    model1.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model1.add(Flatten())

    model2 = Sequential()
    #input 
    model2.add(Dense(32, input_shape=(NUM_FEAT1,1)))
    model2.add(Activation("elu"))
    model2.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model2.add(Dense(16))
    model2.add(Activation("elu"))
    model2.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model2.add(Flatten())

merged = Concatenate()([model1.output,model2.output])
z = Dense(128, activation="relu")(merged)
z = Dropout(0.25)(z)
z = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(z)
z = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(z)

model = Model(inputs=[model1.input, model2.input], outputs=z)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


        model.fit([x_train[train_index][:,:66], x_train[train_index][:,66:132], y_train[train_index], batch_size=100, epochs=100, verbose=2)
```

By this you are able to feed 2 different types of data to your model like images in first model and Textual Data in the second model according to your need.

Comment: @Sohab, in my case I am training CNN model with the generator (flow from directory). How can it be concatenated in this case?

Comment: I didnt tried it for generator but will try and let you know on weekend

Answer (score 0):

You can add CNN and LSTM layers in one model, with Keras. You might encounter problems with the shapes.

Example:

```
def CNN_LSTM():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Convolution2D(input_shape = , filters = , kernel_size = 
    , activation = )
    model.add(LSTM(units = , )

   return model
```

You'll just have to add your parameters. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

I don't think this exactly answers your question, but instead of doing ONLY that, you may consider running dozens of ML models on your data sets and see which works best.  You can use AoutML or DataRobot for these tasks.

https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/automl-the-next-wave-of-machine-learning-5494baac615f

https://www.forbes.com/sites/janakirammsv/2018/06/04/datarobot-puts-the-power-of-machine-learning-in-the-hands-of-business-analysts/#5e9586ea4306